# How reduce mysql cpu usage In the below case

Tags: php, mysql, performance, cpu-usage

I am creating a campaign tracking site. This is having 100 of tables. I am creating a new table for each month for logging my searches and clicks using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` (The table consists of 23 fields and 9 indexes.). My client is complaining about this query they are telling its hogging up alot of CPU. It’s running on every request. But I am creating this table if it’s not exist ie, once per month. Will this increase CPU usage? If yes ,is there any way to reduce CPU usage in this case?

***EDIT 1***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS click_log_201305 (
                      hit_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
                      link_id int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
                      word varchar(225) NOT NULL default '',
                      ppc_engine varchar(40) NOT NULL default 'internal',
                      ppc_commission varchar(10) default NULL,
                      gross_price decimal(5,3) NOT NULL default '0.000',
                      price decimal(5,3) NOT NULL default '0.000',
                      hit_date int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
                      hit_time int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
                      affiliate varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
                      account varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
                      commission varchar(10) default NULL,
                      paid_flag char(3) default NULL,
                      roi_code int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
                      roi_sale int(11) default NULL,
                      debug_info varchar(100) default NULL,
                      ip varchar(15) default NULL,
                      referer varchar(200) default NULL,
                      user_agent varchar(200) default NULL,
                                          subid varchar(50) default NULL,
                                          ad_id INT(11) default NULL,
                                          group_id INT(11) default NULL,
                                          country varchar(100) default NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (hit_id),
                      KEY jhcl_date(hit_date),
                      KEY jhcl_src(hit_date,ppc_engine),
                      KEY jhcl_id(hit_date,link_id),
                      KEY jhcl_acct(hit_date,account),
                      KEY jhcl_aff(hit_date,affiliate),
                      KEY jhcl_word(hit_date,word),
                                          KEY jhcl_camp_id(link_id),
                                          KEY jhcl_group_id(group_id),
                                          KEY jhcl_ad_id(ad_id)
                    )
```

Comment: " I am creating a new table for each month for logging my searches and clicks " - not a good design...High CPU often indicates lots of table scans, suggest you create appropriate indexes.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question unless you provide specific details of the problem you are having, like specific query with specific indexes and so on - we cannot read your mind.

Comment: Yes, but what indexes? Schema? Queries?

Comment: @mvp when a campaign is running i am logging its details at that time i am checking whether table for that month exist or not if not create new table

Comment: Create one table for all logging (not one per month) but partition it by month - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-types.html - for better performance. Testing if the table exists is a lot of unnecessary overhead for every single log entry

Comment: Something tells me that using partitioning here will be acute case of premature optimization. His problem is definitely elsewhere.

Comment: @mvp I have added my query. My doubt is if it was a simple query will it take lots of CPU usage?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` is important, but it is just a schema. You should also tell how your `SELECT` queries look like. I think you lack some important indexes, which are needed by your slow queries

Comment: @mvp - his problem is that he's calling that CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS for every single event/click that he wants to log - the solution is to have one table, not one per month... I merely threw a reference to partitioning in because he clearly has a worry about storing data volumes larger than a month in a single table

Comment: @MarkBaker: Per every click? It was absolutely not obvious from the question. Well, this is not very smart thing to do then :)

Comment: @mvp `It’s running on every request`.... yeah, not very smart at all, and no wonder the client is complaining

Comment: @Mark Baker  Actually its done by another programmers. i got this for correction.They are creating tables in each month and merging it into one table. Merged table is having millions of records. So you people are suggesting to make it a single table rather than tables per month?

Comment: One large table, with appropriate indexes is far better than a new table per month (and allows you to get rid of the `create table` completely from your code, so making it a lot faster to do the inserts)... it has the added benefit of allowing queries spanning a month (e.g. last 3 months, last year), and can still be `partitioned` by month if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` to a cron job / scheduled task, and run it 00.00 am every day. Then the query will run only once a day. And when you create a new table add it to separate table (lets say **table_list**), where you keep list of the tables you create.

Then check the table_list first to check whether you have created the table for current month. If you cant find the table in the "**table_list**", you could create the new one.